# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException When Displaying Multiple Data in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have 3 parts of data displayed in one `RecyclerView`:

1. `storyList`
2. `yukulList`
3. `homeList`

When I've tried to display only `storyList` or `yukulList` or `homeList` data in `RecyclerView`, it works. But when I've tried to display more than one data, for example: `storyList && yukulList` or `storyList && yukulList && homeList`, it will show

`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I've tried to add `notifyDataSetChanged()` but it can't works.

**ShowFavouriteList.java**

```
public class ShowFavouriteList extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterFavList.FavListener {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private TextView noFavtsTV;
    AppPreferences appPreferences;
    private SearchView searchView;
    private AdapterFavList yAdapterFavlist;
    private AdapterFavList mAdapterFavlist;
    private AdapterFavList tAdapterFavlist;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_favourite_list);

        SwipeRefreshLayout pullToRefresh = findViewById(R.id.pullToRefresh);
        pullToRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());
            }
        });

        //toolbar logo and desc
        Toolbar topToolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarTidur);
        setSupportActionBar(topToolBar); //munculkan menu ke toolbar
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //this line shows back button

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        noFavtsTV = findViewById(R.id.no_favt_text);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
        SharedPreferences sPTuru = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyTuru", 0);
        SharedPreferences sPHome = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyHome", 0);
        PreferenceMenejer preferenceMenejer = new PreferenceMenejer(sharedPreferences, sPTuru, sPHome);
        appPreferences = new AppPreferences(preferenceMenejer);

        fetchData();

    } // Oncreate

    private void fetchData() {
        List<Story> storyList = appPreferences.getFavouriteCardList();
        List<YukulModel> yukulList = appPreferences.getFavouriteYukul();
        List<HomeModel> homeList = appPreferences.getFavouriteHome();

        if(storyList != null && storyList.size() > 0) {
            showNoFavtText(false);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
            tAdapterFavlist = new AdapterFavList(this, storyList, yukulList, homeList, this, appPreferences);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(tAdapterFavlist);
            tAdapterFavlist.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        if(yukulList != null && yukulList.size() > 0) {
            showNoFavtText(false);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
            yAdapterFavlist = new AdapterFavList(this, storyList, yukulList, homeList, this, appPreferences);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(yAdapterFavlist);
            yAdapterFavlist.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        if(homeList != null && homeList.size() > 0) {
            showNoFavtText(false);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
            mAdapterFavlist = new AdapterFavList(this, storyList, yukulList, homeList, this, appPreferences);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapterFavlist);
            mAdapterFavlist.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemKlik(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, HomeModel modelField, int position) {
        // Tidur List
        List<HomeModel> modelList = appPreferences.getFavouriteHome();

            HomeModel click = modelList.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected: " + click.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            int id = Integer.parseInt(click.getIdStory());

            if (id == 0) {
                startActivity(new Intent(this, DoaPagi.class));
            } else if (id == 1) {
                startActivity(new Intent(this, DoaSore.class));
            } else if (id == 2) {
                startActivity(new Intent(this, DoaWc.class));
            } else if (id == 3) {
                startActivity(new Intent(this, DoaMasjid.class));
            } else if (id == 4) {
                startActivity(new Intent(this, DzikirShalat.class));
            } else if (id == 5) {
                startActivity(new Intent(this, ChildYukul.class));
            } else if (id == 6) {
                startActivity(new Intent(this, DoaPakaian.class));
            } else if (id == 7) {
                startActivity(new Intent(this, ChildTidur.class));
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemTuru(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, Story tField, int position) {
        // Tidur List
        List<Story> storyList = appPreferences.getFavouriteCardList();

            Story clic = storyList.get(position);
            int idTuru = Integer.parseInt(clic.getIdStory());

            if (idTuru == 0) {
                startActivity(new Intent(this, DoaMauTidur.class));
            } else if (idTuru == 1) {
                startActivity(new Intent(this, DoaBangunt.class));
            } else if (idTuru == 2) {
                startActivity(new Intent(this, DoaJimak.class));
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemYukul(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, YukulModel yField, int position) {
        // Tidur List
    }

    private void showNoFavtText(boolean show) {
        noFavtsTV.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE); //jika data yang ditampilkan tidak ada, maka show noFavsTv
        recyclerView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE); //jika data yang ditampilkan tidak ada, maka don't show rV
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_fav, menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        // Associate searchable_tidur configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search_fav).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setMaxWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        // listening to search query text change
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // filter recycler view when query submitted
                mAdapterFavlist.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                // filter recycler view when text is changed
                mAdapterFavlist.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }

    // Agar back button pada halaman induk settings berfungsi
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.search_fav) {
            return true;
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                this.finish();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**AdapterFavList.java**

```
public class AdapterFavList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    public static final String ACTION_LIKE_IMAGE_CLICKED = "action_like_image_button";

    final int VIEW_TYPE_TIDUR = 0;
    final int VIEW_TYPE_YUKUL = 1;
    final int VIEW_TYPE_HOME = 2;

    private Context context;
    private AppPreferences appPreferences;
    private List<Story> storyList;
    private List<YukulModel> yukulList;
    private List<HomeModel> homeList;
    private List<HomeModel> homeListFiltered;
    private List<Object> collection = new ArrayList<Object>();
    private FavListener listener;

    private int changedItemPosition;
    private boolean isLiked;

    public AdapterFavList(Context context, List<Story> storyList, List<YukulModel> yukulList, List<HomeModel> homeList, FavListener listener, AppPreferences appPreferences) {

        this.context = context;
        this.storyList = storyList;
        this.yukulList = yukulList;
        this.homeListFiltered = homeList;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.appPreferences = appPreferences;

        addData();
    }

    public void addData() {
        storyList = appPreferences.getFavouriteCardList();
        yukulList = appPreferences.getFavouriteYukul();
        homeList = appPreferences.getFavouriteHome();

        if(storyList != null && storyList.size() > 0) {
            collection.addAll(storyList);
        }

        if(yukulList != null && yukulList.size() > 0) {
            collection.addAll(yukulList);
        }

        if(homeList != null && homeList.size() > 0) {
            collection.addAll(homeListFiltered);
        }
    }

    public interface FavListener {
        void onItemKlik(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, HomeModel modelField, int position);
        void onItemTuru(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, Story tField, int position);
        void onItemYukul(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, YukulModel yField, int position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_TIDUR) {
            return new tidurViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_story_favourite_list, parent, false));
        }

        if(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_YUKUL) {
            return new yukulViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_favourite_yukul, parent, false));
        }

        if(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_HOME) {
            return new homeViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_fav_home, parent, false));
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Object item = collection.get(position);

        if(holder instanceof tidurViewHolder){
            ((tidurViewHolder) holder).bind(storyList.get(position));
            ((tidurViewHolder) holder).setViewData((Story) item, holder.getAdapterPosition());
        }

        if(holder instanceof yukulViewHolder){
            ((yukulViewHolder) holder).bind(yukulList.get(position));
            ((yukulViewHolder) holder).viewDataYukul((YukulModel) item, holder.getAdapterPosition());
        }

        if(holder instanceof homeViewHolder){
            ((homeViewHolder) holder).bind(homeList.get(position));
            ((homeViewHolder) holder).viewDataHome((HomeModel) item, holder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return collection.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position){

        Object item = collection.get(position);

        if(item instanceof Story) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_TIDUR;
        }

        if(item instanceof YukulModel){
            return VIEW_TYPE_YUKUL;
        }

        if(item instanceof HomeModel){
            return VIEW_TYPE_HOME;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                String charString = charSequence.toString();
                List<HomeModel> homeList = appPreferences.getFavouriteHome();
                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                    homeListFiltered = homeList;
                }
                else {
                    List<HomeModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (HomeModel row : homeList) {

                        if ( row.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) ) {
                            filteredList.add(row);
                        }
                    }

                    homeListFiltered = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = homeListFiltered;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                homeListFiltered = (ArrayList<HomeModel>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    } //Filter

    public void tidurPutHeart(boolean isChecked, Story tidurstory) {
        SharedPreferences tidursharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Turu", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor tidureditor = tidursharedPreferences.edit();
        tidureditor.putBoolean(tidurstory.getIdStory(), isChecked);
        tidureditor.commit();
    }

    public void yukulPutHeart(boolean isChecked, YukulModel yukulstory) {
        SharedPreferences yukulsharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Yukul", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor yukuleditor = yukulsharedPreferences.edit();
        yukuleditor.putBoolean(yukulstory.getIdStory(), isChecked);
        yukuleditor.commit();
    }

    public void homePutHeart(boolean isChecked, HomeModel homestory) {
        SharedPreferences homesharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Home", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor homeeditor = homesharedPreferences.edit();
        homeeditor.putBoolean(homestory.getIdStory(), isChecked);
        homeeditor.commit();
    }

    //ViewHolder
    public class tidurViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView textView;
        private CheckBox likeCheckBox;

        public tidurViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
            likeCheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.like_button_cb);
        } // itemView

        public void bind(final Story item) {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listener != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();

                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.onItemTuru(tidurViewHolder.this, item, position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public void setViewData(final Story story, final int adapterPosition) {

            textView.setText(story.getName());

            if (story.getIsLiked() == 1) {
                likeCheckBox.setChecked(false);
            }
            else {
                likeCheckBox.setChecked(true);
            }

            likeCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    changedItemPosition = adapterPosition;

                    if (buttonView.isPressed()) {
                        if (isChecked) {
                            tidurPutHeart(isChecked, story);
                            appPreferences.saveFavouriteCard(story);
                        }
                        else {
                            isLiked = false;
                            tidurPutHeart(isChecked, story);
                            appPreferences.deleteCard(story.getIdStory());
                            // updateLikes();
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            if(collection.size() == 0) {
                                ((Activity)context).finish();
                                context.startActivity(((Activity) context).getIntent());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        } //setviewdata

        public void updateLikes() {
            if (!isLiked && storyList.get(changedItemPosition).getIsLiked() == 0) { //jika like dicabut (pada posisi hati yang sedang merah) di halaman favourite list
                storyList.get(changedItemPosition).setIsLiked(0); //maka cabut juga warna merah di halaman favourite list
                notifyItemRangeChanged(getAdapterPosition(), collection.size());
                collection.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
            }

        } //updateLikes

    } //tidurViewholder


    //homeViewHolder
    public class homeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView textView;
        private CheckBox likeCheckBox;

        public homeViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
            likeCheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.like_button_cb);
        } // itemView

        public void bind(final HomeModel item) {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listener != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();

                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.onItemKlik(homeViewHolder.this, item, position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public void viewDataHome(final HomeModel story, final int adapterPosition) {

            textView.setText(story.getName());

            if (story.getIsLiked() == 1) {
                likeCheckBox.setChecked(false);
            }
            else {
                likeCheckBox.setChecked(true);
            }

            likeCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    changedItemPosition = adapterPosition;

                    if (buttonView.isPressed()) {
                        if (isChecked) {
                            homePutHeart(isChecked, story);
                            appPreferences.saveFavouriteHome(story);
                        }
                        else {
                            isLiked = false;
                            homePutHeart(isChecked, story);
                            appPreferences.deleteCardHome(story.getIdStory());
                            // updateLikesHome();
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            if(collection.size() == 0) {
                                ((Activity)context).finish();
                                context.startActivity(((Activity) context).getIntent());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        } //setviewdata

        public void updateLikesHome() {
            if (!isLiked && homeList.get(changedItemPosition).getIsLiked() == 0) { //jika like dicabut (pada posisi hati yang sedang merah) di halaman favourite list
                homeList.get(changedItemPosition).setIsLiked(0); //maka cabut juga warna merah di halaman favourite list
                notifyItemRangeChanged(getAdapterPosition(), collection.size());
                collection.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
            }

        } //updateLikes

    } //homeviewholder


    public class yukulViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView textView;
        private CheckBox likeCheckBox;

        public yukulViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
            likeCheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.like_button_cb);
        } //itemview

        public void bind(final YukulModel item) {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listener != null){
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();

                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.onItemYukul(yukulViewHolder.this, item, position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public void viewDataYukul(final YukulModel yukulId, final int adapterPosition) {

            textView.setText(yukulId.getName());

            if (yukulId.getIsLiked() == 1) {
                likeCheckBox.setChecked(false);
            }
            else {
                likeCheckBox.setChecked(true);
            }

            likeCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    changedItemPosition = adapterPosition;

                    if (buttonView.isPressed()) {
                        if (isChecked) {
                            yukulPutHeart(isChecked, yukulId);
                            appPreferences.saveFavouriteYukul(yukulId);
                        }
                        else {
                            isLiked = false;
                            yukulPutHeart(isChecked, yukulId);
                            appPreferences.deleteCardYukul(yukulId.getIdStory());
                            // updateLikeYukul();
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            if(collection.size() == 0) {
                                ((Activity)context).finish();
                                context.startActivity(((Activity) context).getIntent());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        } //viewdatayukul

        public void updateLikeYukul() {
            if (!isLiked && yukulList.get(changedItemPosition).getIsLiked() == 0) { //jika like dicabut (pada posisi hati yang sedang merah) di halaman favourite list
                yukulList.get(changedItemPosition).setIsLiked(0); //maka cabut juga warna merah di halaman favourite list
                notifyItemRangeChanged(getAdapterPosition(), collection.size());
                collection.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
            }
        } //updateLikes

    } //yukulviewholder


} //HomeAdapter
```

**Logcat**

```
2019-07-20 09:54:52.822 6902-6902/com.seadlab.doadandzikir E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.seadlab.doadandzikir, PID: 6902
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.seadlab.doadandzikir.FavouriteList.AdapterFavList.onBindViewHolder(AdapterFavList.java:124)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6482)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6515)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5458)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5724)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3410)
        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3962)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:610)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:132)
        at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
        at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1361)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:869)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1812)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1656)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1565)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:753)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:20672)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6194)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2792)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2319)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1460)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7183)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
2019-07-20 09:54:52.825 6902-6902/com.seadlab.doadandzikir E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Can you help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your adapter, the `collection` list is the only list that's safe to access using `position`. Trying to call `yukulList.get(position)` is guaranteed to eventually throw an exception.

All of these lines in `onBindViewHolder()` are unsafe and should be changed:

> ```
> @Override
> public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
>     // ...
>         ((tidurViewHolder) holder).bind(storyList.get(position));
>     // ...
>         ((yukulViewHolder) holder).bind(yukulList.get(position));
>     // ...
>         ((homeViewHolder) holder).bind(homeList.get(position));
>     // ...
> }
> ```

You can access the "view type" value that you've returned from `getItemViewType()` by calling `holder.getItemViewType()`, and you can use that to determine the right type of view holder and item to use:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Object item = collection.get(position);
    int adapterPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();

    if (holder.getItemViewType() == VIEW_TYPE_TIDUR){
        Story story = (Story) item;
        tidurViewHolder vh = (tidurViewHolder) holder;
        vh.bind(story);
        vh.setViewData(story, adapterPosition);
    } else if (holder.getItemViewType() == VIEW_TYPE_YUKUL){
        YukulModel yukul = (YukulModel) item;
        yukulViewHolder vh = (yukulViewHolder) holder;
        vh.bind(yukul);
        vh.viewDataYukul(yukul, adapterPosition);
    } else if (holder.getItemViewType() == VIEW_TYPE_HOME){
        HomeModel home = (HomeModel) item;
        homeViewHolder vh = (homeViewHolder) holder;
        vh.bind(home);
        vh.viewDataHome(home, adapterPosition);
    }
}
```

Note also that there's no need to actually pass `holder.getAdapterPosition()` into e.g. `setViewData()`, since you can simply call `getAdapterPosition()` from within the `tidurViewHolder` method.

And I would also say that you could combine your `bind()` and `setViewData()` calls into one, which would leave you with this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Object item = collection.get(position);

    if (holder.getItemViewType() == VIEW_TYPE_TIDUR){
        ((tidurViewHolder) holder).bind((Story) item);
    } else if (holder.getItemViewType() == VIEW_TYPE_YUKUL){
        ((yukulViewHolder) holder).bind((YukulModel) item);
    } else if (holder.getItemViewType() == VIEW_TYPE_HOME){
        ((homeViewHolder) holder).bind((HomeModel) item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Although your code can display multiple part of data at the same time, but still having issue with wrong click. I think we should combine arraylists to one list to avoid wrong index and position or pass param or others, so that we can get correct click. But I find it difficult to write in code. Can you help me @Ben P?

Comment: Let's take it one problem at a time. If this solved the IndexOutOfBoundsException problem, I recommend that you open another question with details specific to the click issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove this  `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)` or pass FALSE to it. passing  TRUE to this method means your adapter's object content will not change, but here your changing the adapter  content by performing a QUERY SEARCH on the adapter's content.

Comment: This is incorrect. `setHasFixedSize()` is related to the size on screen of the `RecyclerView`, and not the size of the collection backing the adapter. See documentation for more info: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setHasFixedSize(boolean)

Answer (score 0):

Try using three different recycler view, one for each data, and in the main layout set each recycler view with height = 0dp and weight 0.3, this going to make then each one has the same height and it'll fit perfectly in any screen

Comment: This would work well if OP wanted three different scrolling lists for their three different types of content. If OP wants one single scrolling list, this will not work. @SeadLab can you clarify if you want one list or three?